# Clean/strip program output from unwanted colour sequences before passing to vim quickfix

Tags: gcc, vim

folks.

I'm trying to make output coloration work with vim and gcc. After some research I came to `CFLAGS+=-fdiagnostics-color=always` in my project Makefile. This work as expected until error/warning occurs. The compilation output is colored as expected, but then errorstring is passed to quickfix and everything goes wrong. It is known issue that vim/quickfix does not support Esc color sequences, even plugins like AnsiEsc exist to make vim recognize and show colors, but this does not seem to work for quickfix, at least I was unable to make it work directly for gcc output, while working perfectly fine if I redirect the output if compilation process, then open file in vim and type `:AnsiEsc` and all the colors and strings are shown as expected. But for the in-vim I get some kind of corrupted output with some symbols missing:

```
"^[[01m^[[Ksyscalls.c" [new]
(6 of 10): ^[[m^[[K ^[[01;31m^[[Kerror: ^[[m^[[Kimplicit declaration of function '^[[01m^[[Ktup2^[[m^[[K'; did you mean '^[[01m^[[Kdup2^[[m^[[K'? [^[[01;31m^[[K-Werror=i
mplicit-function-declaration^[[m^[[K]
```

Looks like the correct output should be:

```
^[[01m^[[Ksyscalls.c:142:5:^[[m^[[K ^[[01;31m^[[Kerror: ^[[m^[[Kimplicit declaration of function '^[[01m^[[Ktup2^[[m^[[K'; did you mean '^[[01m^[[Kdup2^[[m^[[K'? [^[[01;
31m^[[K-Werror=implicit-function-declaration^[[m^[[K]
```

My question is there any way to feed program output to sed for example to clean/strip it from unwanted sequences before it get passed to quickfix input?

Or maybe some other elegant solution to make this work altogether?

Comment: Maybe you could point out which symbols are missing? To me, it looks as if Vim tries to turn the escape sequences into printable characters which is what I'd expect to happen.

Comment: Use `auto` instead of `always`.

Comment: @romainl with `auto` I have no colors, just as with not option at all.

Comment: *That*'s the problem you need to investigate, not how to make Vim's quickfix understand ANSI escapes.

Comment: @Friedrich I have updated my question, but I don't think this will help - there is a total mess.

Comment: @romainl there is no problem there, this is just how vim work. It does not support escapes and this is why AnsiEsc-like plugins exist. TERM could be set to `xterm-256color` or `tmux-256color` - vim will ignore escapes while terminal itself is capable to display them.

Comment: No. `auto` means "use color when the output is a TTY and don't use colors when it is not". In other words: you get colors when you do `$ gcc foo bar` in your shell but not when you do `:make` in Vim, which is what you want. If you don't get that with `auto`, then you definitely have a problem.

Comment: Why have colors in the first place? They make warnings and errors stand out for a *human reader*. Now Vim already takes care of collecting the problems into quickfix and extracts file and line. Still having colors would look nice (I'll give you that) but serve no purpose beyond cosmetics. I don't think what you ask for is possible. Using `auto` as per romainl's suggestion is as good as it gets.

Comment: @romainl probably this is because the shell gcc is executed is not interactive, anyway, this does not change anything, vim itself is not able to parse escapes. They should be removed (probably with sed) prior output is parsed against errorformat.